# Send Numbers Ajax-PHP

Tags: php, ajax

how are you? I am new to using Ajax-PHP and I have a problem, I hope I can help. 
The problem is that when sending numbers from Ajax to PHP nothing arrives, sent an Alert () since ajax and if the numbers appear, but they do not in PHP. My code is as follows:

```
//AJAX
function EditarG(Identificador){
    Tel = document.getElementById('Tel').value;
    Iva= document.getElementById('Iva').value; 
    Id_Tienda=document.getElementById('Id_Tienda').value; 
    Nombre= document.getElementById('Nombre').value;     
    Direccion= document.getElementById('Direccion').value;
    Resultados = document.getElementById('Resultados');   
    alert(Tel+" x "+ Iva+" y "+Identificador);
    Ajax=AJAX();
    Ajax.open('GET', "../../PHP/General/EditarGeneral.php?Id_Tienda="+Id_Tienda+"&Nombre="+Nombre+"&Direccion="+Direccion+"&Tel="+Tel+"&Iva="+Iva+"&Identificador="+Identificador);
    Ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (Ajax.readyState == 4) {
            Resultados.innerHTML = Ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    Ajax.send(null) ;    
}


//PHP
<?php
try {
    include '../Conexion.php';
    $Conectate = new Conexion();
    $Conectate->Conectar();
    $Id_Tienda = $_GET['Id_Tienda'];
    $Nombre = $_GET['Nombre'];
    $Direccion = $_GET['Direccion'];
    $Tel = isset($_GET['Tel']);
    $Iva = isset($_GET['Iva']);
    $Identificador = isset($_GET['Identificador']);    
    $String="UPDATE general set id_tienda='$Id_Tienda', nombre='$Nombre', direccion = '$Direccion', tel='$Tel', iva='$Iva' WHERE id_tienda='$Identificador';";
    $Consulta = mysql_query($String);
    if ($Consulta) {
        print $String;
        print 'Los datos han sido actualizados con exito';

    } else {        
        print 'Hubo un error al intentar actualizar los datos';
    }
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    print "no se pudo";
}
```

The specific values ​​are not sent Identificador, Id_Tienda and Iva. I repeat, the other string type values ​​if they appear in PHP, only these three variables have the problem.

Comment: Try to see if your AJAX call really makes needed request by Firefox and its FireBug extention.

Comment: here is a good read to make [ajax call](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), but i will suggest you to use jQuery for this

Comment: I am open to read reviews, could you give me a simple example of jquery, passing eg an integer and a double? Thanks for your answer!